# How do I run a docker-compose container in interactive mode such that other containers see it?

Tags: debugging, docker, docker-compose

The scenario: I set a breakpoint in code, which is mounted (as a volume) into a container, created by docker-compose. The code is an odoo module, so it's part of the odoo container.

There is also a webapp container, which has a link to odoo in order to use the API.

The odoo container doesn't expose the API port because the host doesn't need it; the webapp container can, of course, see it.

```
services:
  odoo:
    volumes:
      - localpath:/mnt/extra-addons-bundles
  webapp:
    links:
      - odoo
```

Of course, the purpose of the breakpoint is to allow me to control the application - so I need a TTY attached. I can do this with `docker-compose run --rm odoo`. However, when I do this, it creates a new container, so the webapp never actually hits it. Plus, it doesn't tell me what the new container is called, so I have to manually figure it out to do that.

I can use `docker exec` to run another odoo in the odoo container but then I have to run it on a new port, and thus change the webapp config to use this new instance.

Is there a way of achieving what I want, i.e. to run the odoo container in interactive mode, such that the webapp container can see it, and without reconfiguring the webapp container?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

```
services:
  odoo:
    volumes:
      - localpath:/mnt/extra-addons-bundles
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  webapp:
    links:
      - odoo
```

I have also added `stdin_open` in case you need it, if you don't just remove it

**Edit-1**

Also if you need to attach to the running container, then you need to use `docker attach` as `docker-compose` doesn't have that functionality

```
docker attach <containername>
```

Comment: As noted, I tried that - but I'm not confident that I made proper use of it. `docker-compose up` will not give me stdin, and `docker-compose run` is the source of the problem. Can you advise on which command I should use after doing this?

Comment: You won't get stdin with docker-compose. The way you run it would be like this. `docker-compose up -d`. Now if you want run on existing container use `docker-compose exec odoo bash`. if you want to attached to the main process in container then use `docker attach <complete_container_name>`

Comment: I had no idea `docker attach` existed. When did that show up? With that and `tty:true` I got what I needed

Comment: @Altreus, updated the answer with that. It's been there for very long, its just that docker-compose doesn't expose that feature

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `tty: true` in the docker-compose file, and `docker attach` to actually get that process attached to your terminal.